# Tortoise client on VisualSVN server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I've been trying to figure out how to browse the root of the server using the Tortoise svn 'Repo browser'. When I go to the root, it doesn't list any folders, and I just get a message,

```
OPTIONS of 'http://example.com:8443':200 OK (http://example.com:8443)
```

Rather than a full list of the folders on the server. I've had a quick poke around on the Visual SVN site and I can't see anything for this. I spend way more time in my project's in Explorer than I do opening new tabs for browsing a server in my browser, just to paste it back into my svn client.

Can anyone point me in the right directions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subversion can enumerate the repositories so they can be seen in a browser. See the SVNListParentPath directive. However, TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to be able to make any sense of it if you enter a URL pointing to your repositories.

[TortoiseSVN list parent path](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#listparentpath)

Answer (score 4):

What is the URL you used in TortoiseSVN 'Repo Browser'? You need to give the URL of the repository (rather than URL of the SVN server) you would like to browse.

- Open VisualSVN Server Manager,
- Right-click on the repository and then click “Copy URL to Clipboard”.
- Paste this URL into TortoiseSVN 'Repo Browser'.

Comment: Also worth to mention: Subversion does not enumerate repositories (thus you cannot just point to the root of a server).

Comment: Ah, which is what I wanted to do. If you could put that in a reply, I can mark it as answered, ta